# Use an encrypted file as your database instead of mongodb for your node/express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, encryption, database

How can I use an encrypted file as your database instead of MongoDB or MySQL for your NodeJS/express app?

where you will give your DB will be of a JSON format and there will be a service that backs it up at regular interval.

It could look like this

```
{
  "info": {
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "Give your DB a name"
  },
  "data": {

  }
}
```

and have methods like

```
myDB.info() // => {"version" : "0.0.2", "name": "demo DB"}

myDB.get('foo'); // => 'bar'

myDB.set('foo', 'bar');

myDB.delete(key);

myDB.backup(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log('DB backed up at %s', new Date().toString());
});

myDB.search('stats.comments_lookup[{stats.page.id}]', function(res) {
    console.log("search result: ", res);
});
```

I saw this npm package called express-db but it's outdated and not maintained. Any better option or way of doing this?

Comment: Using a flatfile instead of a database is a very poor idea.  Consider the fact that, to update the database, one must decrypt, modify the JSON, then encrypt again.  This is definitely not an atomic operation.

Comment: Yeah. That is true. But there must be a scalable approach to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using encrypted database or files, just encrypt data and store it in database.

You can use [crypto-js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encryption 
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
//Store it in any database

//Retrieve from database
// Decryption 
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(plaintext);
```

**Advantage**

In most cases you don't really need to encrypt entire data in a data set. So just encrypt sensitive data and store other data as plain text. Your application will run faster as encryption is really a CPU intensive process.